# What payment gateways fit my website?

Tags: ecommerce, payments, payment-gateway

I am building an image hosting website and users will pay for extra storage, this means that for example: each 1GB over the first 3GB, I will charge the user for some money per GB.

I want to integrate in my website a payment way so that I can let the users pay through and also let me to collect these money later either getting them through ATM or to get it in my bank account.

I can't user paypal because it is not working in my country Egypt.

Can you advice me with a service and some tips about how users will pay and how I will get the money from.

Comment: What is the minimum / maximum / average amount of money m people will pay? Where are your users located?

Comment: users located world wide, and I am not sure yet about min and max but it will be few dollars per payment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a merchant account? If not, you'll need to either open one at a local bank or be restricted to payment gateways that allow direct deposit into regular banking/checking accounts. There are also online merchant account providers that also offer an online payment processing gateway.

What you choose should depend on the payment sizes/quantities and the rates offerred by different vendors. Some vendors/plans charge a monthly fee + a percentage of each transaction, others charge a flat rate on a per-transaction basis. If you have few transactions, and they're very large transfers, then obviously a flat fee is best. In your case, it's not so clear. You'll need to get a list of rates and do the math yourself.

Also, if you're using a pre-existing e-commerce app or library/framework, then the gateways/standards your software supports will also be a deciding factor.

Your local bank will most-likely have a business banking department that can offers merchant services, including merchant accounts as well as a list of online payment processing gateways that they have a relationship with. So that would be an easy way to get a list of payment gateways which work in your country.